# How can the content of a UITableViewCell be updated properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a `TableView` whose cells content need to be updated when it's `TableViewRowAction` is excecuted. More precisely I want to update a `UILabel` inside the cell. Setting a new text to this label inside the action is no problem but when scrolling down/up and the cell gets reloaded, then this label inside the cell has the same text as before changing it.

I know that the cells get reused and that's why I want to know how to "avoid" this effect and how to update the content of the cells properly. I have already tried to call `TableView.ReloadData()` which seems to solve the problem but the cells appear in a completly different order which doesn't look very nice.

Comment: You need to ensure that you update the data model as well as the cell. Show your `cellForRow` code as well as your action handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to update the data that your `UITableView` is drawing from (i.e. the array of data that you're populating each cell from has been updated to reflect your text change), then reload the specific cell of the `UITableView`:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: When I am reloading the affected row with `.reloadRows()`, although the update is performing well the cell is getting moved to another postion. Before reloading the row I set the source for the table.

Comment: Perfect, so call the reloadRows `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` method at EXCLUSIVELY the row you want to reload. As long as you know the row & section of the row you need to reload, you can create the indexPath of that row, and reload it easily, without causing the WHOLE THING to reload!

Comment: I got it. I fixed the issue that the cell was moving to a new position. The only problem left is that the `UITableView` flickers and "jumps around" for a short moment. Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: Has it maybe something to do with the `TableViewRowAction`'s animation?

Comment: Possible! Try `uitableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`

Comment: Well, the issue was that I didn't set `TableView.EstimatedRowHeight`. Now there is no glitching anymore when reloading a row, but a new problem (it doesn't seem to come to an end) is that I also want to delete rows sometimes and the animation can't be excecuted properly because of the row height.

Comment: Ahhh awesome! Nice job figuring it out! You should post your answer, and mark it as solved!

Comment: Sure, I will do that. But it seems that you also don't know a workaround the new animation problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

As you said table cells are reused , this means you have to keep a model array for the whole table and make all the changes to it , then reload the table more importantly to set the content of the cell index in `cellForRowAt`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you must create an Array that acts as a dataSource for your labels. When you are changing the text for a specific label, you must update the array. You can get the exact update location from the property `indexPath` of the method `cellForRowAt`. Every single time you scroll up and down, `cellForRowAt` method is called. Just use something like

```
label.text = array[indexPath.row]
```